# How to send SMS from terminal in background on Android?

Tags: sms, shell, terminal, command-line

I'm trying to send text message (SMS) from my Android terminal app in background (sim 1 or 2).

I can send message in foreground using this command:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:121 --es sms_body "test text" --ez exit_on_sent true;
input keyevent 22;
input keyevent 66;
```

But this command don't work in background.

So, how can I send message in background from my terminal?
**Note: Android version 6.0. Rooted device**

Comment: With "terminal" you mean an app like Termux or do you mean `adb`? If it is an terminal app does it have the permission `SEND_SMS`?

Comment: app like termux and permission set ok!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that appears to work as attested over at our sister site [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224091) is and is explains in detail:

`adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "Hey\ you\ !" s16 "null" s16 "null"`

> "Isms method number (5 and 7 above) may change with the android version . Read full explanation to understand it."

Comment: It's not working. just display **Result: Parsel(00000000, '....')**

Comment: Firstly, you need to get the actual Service/package name for the service you are trying to call. You can get a list of Your devices Services by throwing the command: `adb shell dumpsys -l`. Look, for the Service'(s) with `mms` it will have a syntax of something com.whatevs `mms`.service. located use that in your command instead of just coping and pasting. Also inform me of the actual name and I will edit the answer. Lastly, reading the extremely detailed answer by @Taknok expailing the what's going on the subid is could be wrong too.

Comment: In my terminal `dumpsys -l` show nothing. But if I run `service list` it's showing **imms com.android.internal.telephony.IMms** and another one isms.

Comment: Try both but first try the isms one just because that's the command your throwing. If that is a no go then try the Imms one. Also if you can look at the manifest you can most likely get the subid along with the service you need to utilize to send an SMS.

Comment: also not working. However I build an apk for solving my problem. Thank you for your answer.